# match two sets of combination of numbers

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
T1 T2 T3 R1 R2 R3
3  4  2  3  2  1
6  4  2  2  1  4
8  7  6  6  7  8
```

I am trying to match the combination of the first set of numbers (T1, T2, T3) to the second (R1, R2, R3) to see if there is a match.

For example:

Line1:

The numbers are 3,4,2 in the first section of T1, T2, T3

The numbers are 3,2,1 in the second section of R1, R2, R3

So there is no match here.

Line2 (also no match)

Line3:
The numbers are 8,7,6 in the first section of T1, T2, T3

The numbers are 6,7,8 in the second section of R1, R2, R3

There is a match here, as all three numbers exist in both sections (the order doesn't matter).

Desired output:

```
T1 T2 T3 R1 R2 R3  MATCH
3  4  2  3  2  1   No Match
6  4  2  2  1  4   No Match
8  7  6  6  7  8   Match
```

So far I have tried to use `match` and also combine each of the combinations but I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to use `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` and then compare the first 3 elements with the next 3 elements and wrap it with `all`

```
c("No Match", "Match")[apply(df1, 1, function(x) all(sort(x[1:3]) == sort(x[4:6]))) + 1]
#[1] "No Match" "No Match" "Match"
```

---

Or another option is `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
rownames_to_column(df1, 'rn') %>%
     gather(key, val, -rn) %>% 
     group_by(rn) %>% 
     summarise(MATCH = all(sort(val[str_detect(key, "^T")]) == 
                           sort(val[str_detect(key, "^R")]))) %>%
     pull(MATCH) %>% 
     bind_cols(df1, MATCH = .)
```

NOTE: It is better to keep as a logical (TRUE/FALSE) instead of `Match/No Match`

Answer (score 3):

We can use `apply` to check for every row (MARGIN = 1) if all the elements in first three columns are present in last three. Use this in `ifelse` to get the required string.

```
df$MATCH <- ifelse(apply(df, 1, function(x) all(x[1:3] %in% x[4:6])),
                                           "Match", "No match")

df 
#  T1 T2 T3 R1 R2 R3    MATCH
#1  3  4  2  3  2  1 No match
#2  6  4  2  2  1  4 No match
#3  8  7  6  6  7  8    Match
```